# How do I add an actionbar menu in my fragment using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-actionbar, fragment

How do I add an actionbar menu in my fragments using Kotlin? When I run the code below nothing shows up.

class Fragment1: Fragment() {
    private lateinit var fview: View

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View?{
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        dissview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dissability, container, false)

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)


    return fview

}//end on create


override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the contents of R.menu.mainmenu.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemminfo"
        android:title="Itemmoreinfo" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/itemabout"
        android:title="ItemAbout" />
</menu>

Comment: Thank you, but please edit your original post to include it. Comments do not retain formatting so code posted in them is not easily comprehended.